# Exchange Web Services - read subfolders

Tags: c#, webdav, exchangewebservices

I use Exchange Web Services (EWS) from Microsoft.

My code is like this:

```
ExchangeService server = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
```

etc.

I get the folders using this code:

```
Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(server, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
```

The structure of my folders on Exchange Server is:

```
Inbox
|
|
Folder1
|
|_Sub_Folder1
| |
| |_Sub_Sub_Folder1
|   |
|   |_Sub_Sub_Sub_Folder1
|
|_Sub_Folder2
| |
| |_Sub_Sub_Folder1
|
Folder2
|
|_Sub_Folder1
|
|_Sub_Folder2
```

When I use function which is presented above, I receive only the major folders :

`Inbox`, `Folder1` and `Folder2`.

I would like to receive `SubFolders`... as well and next I would like to get items from `SubFolders`.

For Example:

```
Folder1
|
|_Sub_Folder1
| |
| |_Sub_Sub_Folder1
|   |
|   |_Sub_Sub_Sub_Folder1 -> I want to get these items
```

Could you help me and provide me an example of some code? What function should I use?

I tried to use:

```
FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults2 = folder.FindFolders(new FolderView(100));
```

But when I receive for example folders: `Inbox`, `Folder1`, `Folder2` and I read `ChildFolderCount`, I don't receive number of `subfolders` ex. `2` -> I receive count `0`.

What is wrong? I need to read these items from `subfolders`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590510/find-all-subfolders-of-the-inbox-folder-using-ews

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 questions. 
The first one: "how to get subfolders" and second one "Why is ChildFolderCoun = 0".

The answer to the second one is pretty easy. You have to call folder.Load() and provide a propertyset which is including the FolderSchema.ChildFolderCount propertydefinition.

The answer to your first question is, that you will have to call FindFolders() for each folder in a recusive loop. At least I didn't find a param or something like that which tell's the FindFolders-Method to include all subfolders.

Hope that helps you...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for method to validate if folder exist or not. You can use below method. It recursively searches each subfolders.  Change the FolderView's Traversal property for deep / shallow search.

```
FolderId subfolderInfo;
// Call Method
bool folderExist = isFolderExist(exchange, "Folder1", out subfolderInfo);

//Implementation 

private bool isFolderExist(ExchangeService exchange, string subFolder, out FolderId subfolderInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
                view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
                view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
                view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
                FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = exchange.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);
                foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults)
                {
                    if (folder.DisplayName == subFolder)
                    {                        
                        subfolderInfo = folder.Id;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
               ...
            }          
            subfolderInfo = null;
            return false;
        }
```